# How to debug windows phone application in windows 10 hosted in Azure?

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, hyper-v, visual-studio-emulator

I can't debug windows phone application in windows 10 hosted in Azure. The emulator of windows phone can't start because hyper-v in hosted windows is disabled. 
Do you somebody know any workaronud ? I have BizSpark subscription and I want develop and test mobile application in remote machine without install any third party tools (if is it possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuriy,

From what I know,you can't.

The Windows Phone emulator runs in virtualization, and you can't run a virtual machine in a virtual machine.

So the Windows Phone Emmulator can't be in Azure.

Install it on a real computer

Regards

Comment: Is this still the case as of oct 2016?